# Magento create new order based on anonymous checkout client

Tags: orders, backend, sales

we have "allow anonymous" checkout enabled because we see - that creating an account can sometimes defer customers.

Now when I create a new order based on that (specific anonymous) customer I have to enter all the customer data manually again.

What I mena is that the email, address and other information is already in another order. But when I create a new order - the customer is not in the customer list.

What I would normally do is: open the previous order and lookup all the information. What would be great is: that there is a button that says: create new order for this customer (and copies all the customer data fields)

Question: is there a fast way to copy the customer data from a previous order so I only have to add a product?

major thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature that allows a previous guest customer's information to be copied for new guest order. However, you can write an extension that does this.

I suggest creating an extension that mimics the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::reorderAction()` and copy over only information you need for the new guest order you want to create.